# how to change the displayed timezone from a bat file

Tags: batch-file, time, output

I am running a small .bat script to output the system time to a text file to then be imported to OBS. The project it is being used for however needs to have the time displayed in Central time instead of Eastern (my time zone). Is it possible to change the outputs time zone without changing the timezone on my computer's clock?

```html
:loop

time /T > C:\Users\Brennan\Desktop\time\time.txt

time /T

timeout /t 15

goto loop
```

Comment: See ` wmic os get CurrentTimeZone` and  `tzutil /?``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `wmic path win32_utctime get` outputs UTF-16 Little Endian encoded:

```
Day  DayOfWeek  Hour  Milliseconds  Minute  Month  Quarter  Second  WeekInMonth  Year
16   0          11                  12      7      3        19      4            2017
```

This output can be parsed with command **FOR** and concatenated to a UTC date/time string in international date/time format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` wit command **SET**.

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,3,4,5,7,9" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe path win32_utctime get') do (
    set "Day=0%%A"
    set "Hour=0%%B"
    set "Minute=0%%C"
    set "Month=0%%D"
    set "Second=0%%E"
    set "Year=%%F"
    goto BuildDateTime
)

:BuildDateTime
set "DateTimeUTC=%Year%-%Month:~-2%-%Day:~-2% %Hour:~-2%:%Minute:~-2%:%Second:~-2%"
echo UTC date/time is: %DateTimeUTC%
```

The output of this batch file for the data posted above is:

```
UTC date/time is: 2017-07-16 11:12:19
```

The code can be also modified to get just UTC time:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1 tokens=3,4,7" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe path win32_utctime get') do (
    set "Hour=0%%A"
    set "Minute=0%%B"
    set "Second=0%%C"
    goto BuildTime
)

:BuildTime
set "TimeUTC=%Hour:~-2%:%Minute:~-2%:%Second:~-2%"
echo UTC time is: %TimeUTC%
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic path /?`
- `wmic path win32_utctime /?`
- `wmic path win32_utctime get /?`

Answer (score 0):

The zone may be set via tzutil but it is a global (systemwide) change -- the setlocal command will not localize it.  The following will *temporarily* change the desired zone, by saving and restoring it:

```
for /f "delims=" %%z in ('tzutil /g') do (
  rem set desired zone
  tzutil /s "Central Standard Time"

  time /T > C:\Users\Brennan\Desktop\time\time.txt

  rem restore original zone
  tzutil /s "%%z"
)
```

Note the change is systemwide, so the period between tzutil calls the system clock will change.  And if the script is aborted between tzutil calls the system time zone will remain altered.